# M1 Chip Node Sass conflict

Tags: php, sass, apple-m1, node-sass

I'm working on iMac M1 for my Symfony project, and as it happened to many of us, Node Sass turned out to be incompatible with M1 chip.

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Missing binding /Users/clara/PhpstormProjects/tag/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-93/binding.node
> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 16.x
> Found bindings for the following environments: - OS X Unsupported architecture (arm64) with Node.js 16.x

I searched a lot on internet, I saw many ways to fix it, but no one worked for me...

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^2.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.6.1",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
        "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "sass": "^1.43.4"
    }
}
```

I'm using Node v16, and tried the following methods:

- `npm rebuild node-sass`
- Add options in webpack.config.js:

```
.enableSassLoader(options => {
        options.implementation = require('sass');
    })
```

- delete node_modules directory and launch `npm install`
- install sass in devDependencies:

```
npm uninstall -D node-sass
npm install -D sass
```

- Install sass instead of node-sass as recommended by LibSass
- target arch for running it through Rosetta with:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --target_arch=x64
```

Is there someone having another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Node version is V14.X . try this way.

open terminal through rosetta2, and then type this

```sh
arch -x86_64 zsh
```

if it didn't work try to switch you node version to 14.x through nvm